# How to Pass values to Custom Field through PHP in WordPress Posts?

Tags: custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

Suppose i have a function

```
function mytable(){
$count_value = get_kudos_count( $post_id ); }
```

How to send `$count_value` dynamically to the custom field present in WordPress post ?

Let us assume the custom field name (key) is `custom_count`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`update_post_meta`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta):

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'custom_count', $count_value );
```

Comment: can you briefly explain it. 
where i should place the function,
and send the output values to the field custom_count.

Comment: I have no idea what the purpose of your function is, so I don't know where you need to put it.

Comment: It worked, since i am using ACF plugin i used update_field() function.